# HTML5 img Element & srcset: width vs sizes

Tags: html, image, srcset

HTML5 allows the inclusion of the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes on images. I haven’t read anything about how a browser will react if an image has both a `width` attribute and a `sizes` attribute.

My guess is that `sizes` (provided that there is a `srcset` to go with it) should take precedence. Can anybody tell me where the official word is on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `sizes` attribute influences which resource in `srcset` gets chosen, and it affects the image's intrinsic pixel density, and hence, the rendered size of the image *but only if you have not specified its dimensions with CSS or `width`/`height` attributes*.